# Logging User IP to DB in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been struggling with this for ages and none of the related questions seem to be of use. I am trying to collect the User's IP via a hidden field, and then display it on the applicable message. When I try to implement it I get the following error on my form page. I'm not sure whether it's due to an issue with updating the tables or what, but the value ip does not come up when I run Message.all [image]
Here is the the relevant code:
Console when running Messages.all:

```
irb(main):002:0> Message.all
  Message Load (2.6ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Message id: 30, subject: "Pears", content: "Pears", post_time: nil, created_at: "2015-07-02 19:49:32", updated_at: "2015-07-02 19:49:32">, #<Message id: 31, subject: "Pears", content: "Pears\r\n", post_time: nil, created_at: "2015-07-14 17:49:12", updated_at: "2015-07-14 17:49:12">, #<Message id: 32, subject: "Hi", content: "Muffin", post_time: nil, created_at: "2015-07-14 17:52:23", updated_at: "2015-07-14 17:52:23">]>
irb(main):003:0>
```

Migration File for Messages Model:

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.string :subject
      t.string :content
      t.string :ip
      t.date :post_time

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Messages Controller:

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @messages=Message.all
    end
    def new
        @messages=Message.new
    end
    def show
        @message=Message.find(params[:id])
    end
    def destroy
        @messages=Message.find(params[:id])
        @messages.destroy
        redirect_to '/'
    end
    def create
        @messages = Message.new(message_params) 
            if @messages.save 
            redirect_to '/' 
                else 
            render 'new' 
            end
    end
    private
    def message_params
        params.require(:message).permit(:content, :subject, :id, :ip)
    end

end
```

Submit Message View:

```
<div class="formWrapper">
    <%=form_for Message.new do |t|%>
    <div class ="Inputs">
        <div class="row">

        <div class="input-field col s6">
        <%=t.text_field :subject, :class => "validate", :length => '25', :placeholder => 'Subject'%><br>
        <%=t.text_area :content, :class => "materialize-textarea", :placeholder => "Message"%>
        <%=t.hidden_field :ip, :value => request.remote_ip %>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=""></div>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="submit">
            <%=t.submit "Submit", :class => "btn"%>

        </div>

        <%end%>
    </div>
</div>
```

Index Page(Where Messages are Displayed):

```
<div class="main">

        <%@messages.each do |t|%>
        <div class="cWrap">
        <div class="col s12 m6">
        <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
        <div class="card-content white-text">
        <span class="card-title"><%=link_to t.subject, show_path(t)%></span>
        <div class="divider"></div>
        <p><%=t.content%></p>
        <p><%=t.ip%></p>
        </div>
            <div class="card-action">
                <%=link_to "Delete Message", delete_path(t), :method => 'delete'%>
            </div>

        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Does any of your saved message contains an `ip`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this is very bad idea, everyone can change IP in form directly (for example by chrome dev tools)... Its better to set the ip before you save message in controller:

```
@message = Message.new(message_params)
@message.ip = request.remote_ip
@message.save
```

The next thing, if you look into console

```
irb(main):002:0> Message.all
  Message Load (2.6ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Message id: 30, subject: "Pears", content: "Pears", post_time: nil, created_at: "2015-07-02 19:49:32", updated_at: "2015-07-02 19:49:32">, #<Message id: 31, subject: "Pears", content: "Pears\r\n", post_time: nil, created_at: "2015-07-14 17:49:12", updated_at: "2015-07-14 17:49:12">, #<Message id: 32, subject: "Hi", content: "Muffin", post_time: nil, created_at: "2015-07-14 17:52:23", updated_at: "2015-07-14 17:52:23">]>
irb(main):003:0>
```

There is no **ip** attribute of object Message! It looks like you add the **ip** field into already applied migration, please rollback and migrate again (to create Message table) or remove **t.string :ip** and create new migration to just add ip to messages table:

```
def change
  add_column :messages, :ip, :string
end
```

Comment: How would do I add the column?

Comment: Create a new migration **rails g migration AddIpToMessages** and in content of change method will be: **add_column :messages, :ip, :string** and apply that **rake db:migrate** or rollback current messages **rake db:rollback** and aply that again **rake db:migrate**...

Comment: Ok I got the Ip Column added, but the value of my IP column for my message is "::1", is that Rubyese for localhost?

Comment: Yes it is localhost and it is not **ruby** invention, it's standard shorthand for ipv6 localhost https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

Answer (score 0):

```
irb(main):002:0> Message.all 
Message Load (2.6ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM "messages"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Message id: 30, subject: "Pears", content: "Pears", post_time: nil, created_at: "2015-07-02 19:49:32", updated_at: "2015-07-02 19:49:32">, #<Message id: 31, subject: "Pears", content: "Pears\r\n", post_time: nil, created_at: "2015-07-14 17:49:12", updated_at: "2015-07-14 17:49:12">, #<Message id: 32, subject: "Hi", content: "Muffin", post_time: nil, created_at: "2015-07-14 17:52:23", updated_at: "2015-07-14 17:52:23">]> irb(main):003:0>
```

As I can see, there is no `ip` attribute in your any of the messages. I guess you add that field later on the migration file and forget to migrate.